# powershell script that initiates a 2nd script

Tags: powershell

Here is the code;

```powershell
Get-Content -path c:\batchjobs\location\test.log -pattern -lt "2" > sleep -seconds (60) elseif -pattern -gt "2" | C:\batchjobs\location\output.txt
```

All I need it to do is open/initiate the `output.txt` file, this will send an email when the pattern conditions are met.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "*All I need it to do is open/initiate the output.txt file*" - I'm not clear what that means. Is output.txt a batch file? A powershell file? Do you want to email output.txt somewhere? Open it in notepad?

Comment: 'output.txt' is just a place holder, I have a 2nd powershell script this will initiate

Comment: So if I understand correctly, are you trying to go line-by-line through *test.log* and email someone if a condition is met? If so, what is an example of a line in *test.log* and what pattern are you trying to match? The `-pattern -lt "2"` is not clear to me.

Comment: there is only one line a number, between 1 and 7 digits long, if the number exceeds a certain threshold it should trigger the email

Comment: -pattern -lt "2" is what I am looking for in the string, it it exceeds that number it will initiate the 2nd script

Comment: Don't forget to mark your questions as answered - that increases your reputation and removes it from the list of unanswered questions. I notice all the questions you asked don't have anything marked as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entire content of *test.log* is a single number, made with padded spaces and maybe blank lines, then you can do

```
if (((Get-Content .\test.log) -join '').Trim() -gt 2) { .\my_script.ps1 }
```

If you need the actual number there for the your script to parse, then you want something more like

```
$x = ((Get-Content .\test.log) -join '').Trim();
if ($x -gt 2)
{
    .\my_script.ps1 $x
}
```

If you need it on a single line, such as for use with `powershell -Command` from a non-powershell command line, you can just eliminate the newlines:

```
$x = ((Get-Content .\test.log) -join '').Trim(); if ($x -gt 2) { .\my_script.ps1 $x }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little safer. This will store the resulting number in $x. It for some reason the content of the file contains characters that cannot be parsed into an integer, $x will contain 0 and $parsedOk will be $false.

```
$x=$null
$parsedOk = [int64]::TryParse($(gc .\test.log),[ref]$x)
if($parsedOk -and $x -gt 2){
    .\my_script.ps1 $x
}
```